# STM8 alarm firing shortly after resetting time

Tags: microcontroller, timer, interrupts, st, stm8

I'm using an STM8L151F3 with the SPL, compiled with SDCC. I'm trying to generate an alarm interrupt after n seconds, then another after m seconds.

To do that, I reset the time to 0, then set the alarm time to n seconds. Wait for the interrupt, then reset time again and set alarm time to m seconds. I'm masking minutes/hours/dateweekday.

It works mostly as it's supposed to, except after resetting the time for the n seconds timer, an extra alarm interrupt is immediately generated. If I ignore that, the normally timed interrupt is generated.

I can solve this issue by comparing the RTC time to what the alarm was supposed to fire and ignore it if it doesn't match. But I would like to figure out why this is happening.

In this partial example, it would reset time, get an interrupt immediately, reset time, wait 10 seconds, get an interrupt, reset time, immediately get another interrupt, reset time, wait 10 seconds...

```
RTC_InitTypeDef   RTC_init_conf;
RTC_AlarmTypeDef  RTC_alarm_conf;
RTC_TimeTypeDef   RTC_time;

uint8_t alarm_status = 0;

static inline void init_rtc(void){
    RTC_DeInit();

    //use LSI clock
    CLK_RTCClockConfig(CLK_RTCCLKSource_LSI, CLK_RTCCLKDiv_1);

    CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_Peripheral_RTC, ENABLE);

    //AN3133 pg.20
    RTC_init_conf.RTC_HourFormat    = RTC_HourFormat_24;

    //38 kHz -> 1Hz RTC
    RTC_init_conf.RTC_AsynchPrediv  = 124;
    RTC_init_conf.RTC_SynchPrediv   = 303;

    RTC_Init(&RTC_init_conf);

    ///* reset time to 0 */
    RTC_TimeStructInit(&RTC_time);
    RTC_SetTime(RTC_Format_BIN, &RTC_time);

    /* only care about seconds, mask everything but it */
    RTC_alarm_conf.RTC_AlarmMask = RTC_AlarmMask_Minutes | RTC_AlarmMask_Hours | RTC_AlarmMask_DateWeekDay;

    RTC_alarm_conf.RTC_AlarmTime.RTC_Seconds = 5;

    /* enable alarm interrupt */
    RTC_ITConfig(RTC_IT_ALRA, ENABLE);

    RTC_AlarmCmd(DISABLE);
}

static inline void set_timer(void){
    RTC_AlarmCmd(DISABLE);

    /* reset time to 0 */
    RTC_TimeStructInit(&RTC_time);
    RTC_SetTime(RTC_Format_BIN, &RTC_time);

    //example times
    if(RTC_alarm_conf.RTC_AlarmTime.RTC_Seconds == 5){
        RTC_alarm_conf.RTC_AlarmTime.RTC_Seconds = 10;
    } else {
        RTC_alarm_conf.RTC_AlarmTime.RTC_Seconds = 5;
    }

    RTC_SetAlarm(RTC_Format_BIN, &RTC_alarm_conf);
    RTC_AlarmCmd(ENABLE);
}

/**
 * @brief RTC / CSS_LSE Interrupt routine.
 */
INTERRUPT_HANDLER(RTC_CSSLSE_IRQHandler,4) {
    /* alarm */
    if(RTC_GetITStatus(RTC_IT_ALRA)){
        RTC_ClearITPendingBit(RTC_IT_ALRA);

        alarm_status = 1;
    }
}

void main(void){
    init_stuff();
    init_rtc();

    while(1){
        wfi();

        if(alarm_status){
            alarm_status = 0;
            puts("alarm fired");
            set_alarm();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the `RTC_SetTime` function, but almost certainly it's not changing the time in a single atomic operation, but doing a whole sequence of writes.... and somewhere in the middle of that sequence, the "current" time matches the "alarm" time and fires the interrupt.  Try uploading the new alarm configuration before zeroing the time.  Or if you don't need to save every last instruction, do it right and turn off the alarm before making changes to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to use some fixed time interrupt, like 1ms. If possible use systick timer interrupt if your MCU supports. Then you can write multiple instances of timers: on-delay, of-delay, pulse,...you can find some IEC timer examples from PLC manuals. These do increment, compare, set output flag according to elapsed time. They are all updated at fixed interval (systick). In my opinion you don't need a nanosecond/microsecond precise timing, so you cold use a single hw timer interrupt to update all timer instances.

Comment: This MCU doesn't have a systick timer. I am using the periodic wakeup timer (WUT) for the main program loop. The main reason why I would like to use the alarm peripheral is that this is an ultra-low power application on battery. The RTC is able to keep running during deep sleep. Using one of the other timers would use significantly more power.

Comment: I see now, but your code 1st is not complete, there are functions never called, 2nd  there are calls to functions that are not declared, 3rd there is no definition of RTC_time, 4th there is no such sleep/wake-up mechanism you do mention.

Comment: Correct, it isn't my whole project